# Trying to read a JSON file into a Map using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON file with this structure...

```
{"id":"1","name":"name","categories":["category1","category2","category3"],"type":"store"}
{"id":"2","name":"name","categories":["category1","category2","category3"],"type":"store"}
```

which doesn't have a key or commas separating each object.  So when I use this code...

```
    File input = new File("test.json");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map obj = mapper.readValue(input, Map.class);
```

the obj variable only has the first line in the json file which makes sense as it doesn't know what the key is.

I tried adding one by wrapping the objects like so...

```
{ "Key": [

    {"id":"1","name":"name","categories":["category1","category2","category3"],"type":"store"},
    {"id":"2","name":"name","categories":["category1","category2","category3"],"type":"store"}
] }
```

including adding the commas to separate each as the file did not have any commas to separate them.

While this works...

1. I have multiple json files that I have to work with
2. The file sizes are a bit big so it takes a long time to add they "Key" wrap like I did in the example.

I'm hoping to avoid this altogether but not sure if I can.  Is there a way to read the json file using the original format into a Map so I can then filter the data as needed?

Comment: If you assume that each line is an object, what's the point of wrapping everything in an array and adding separating commas? Why not just parse each line separately instead?

Comment: I need to filter them by the category (or other fields) so I need them to be in format that I can access and then process.  I was trying to follow another q/a which had similar lines like above to put the json objects into the map but the format the json is in currently will not work unless I wrap and add commas

Comment: Yes, it will. Every JSON object can be parsed to a map (just as if they were wrapped into a JSON array), and you can do whatever you want withthese maps.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I was overthinking it and didn't think of just iterating over line by line and putting it into the map.  Makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution that doesn't require file modification. Read your file line by line and then feed a single line to your `ObjectMapper`. You will get Many instances of Maps that you can store in a List, JsonArray or another map that you will need to create in your code. your code make look like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Object> list = new ArrayList<>()
try (
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.json")))) {
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  Map obj = mapper.readValue(line, Map.class);
  list.add(obj)
}
```

Comment: Ah ok.  That makes sense / should work.  Thank you.  I was thinking there may be some other way to read in the json but just iterating line by line will work

Comment: If your entire file was a valid JSON then yes you could do it. But your file is a collection of separate JSONs, so you have to parse each JSON separately

Comment: Ah ok got it.  First time dealing with a JSON file so assumed what was provided was standard till I started working with it.  Thanks again